# SwiftUi Transition / Animation

Tags: swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and have managed to build simple game.
 All works except my plan to implement some sort of image animation / transition to introduce the image into the view.
The images are formatted correctly, but too abrupt and hoped to soften the image glow
 I have tried by using the animation method, but has not mad a difference.
 I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

```
    var body: some View {


        NavigationView {

            ZStack {

                Image("background")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)


                VStack {

                        Text("Tap Correct Image")

                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)

                    ForEach((0...2), id: \.self) { number in

                        Image(self.naijaObject[number])
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .border(Color.black,width: 1)
                            .transition(.slide)
                            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.pictureTapped(number)
                        }


                    }


                    .navigationBarTitle(Text(processCorrectAnswer))
                    .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                        Alert(title: Text("\(alertTitle), Your score is \(score)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                            self.askQuestion()
                        })
                    }
                }//End of VStack

            }//End of

        } //End of Naviagtion View


    } //End of View

    //Function to action which object is tapped
           func pictureTapped(_ tag: Int) {
               if tag == correctAnswer {

                score += 1
                alertTitle = "Correct"
               } else {

                score -= 1
                alertTitle = "Wrong"
               }
            showAlert = true
           }

    //Function to continue the game
    func askQuestion() {
        naijaObject.shuffle()
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, what you want to achieve, but in future better to present more code. Here I used `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)` where I change the variable `showAlert` to `true`. And it works smoothly, hope it'll help you:

```swift
struct QuestionGame: View {

    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var score: Int = 0
    @State private var correctAnswer = 1
    @State private var tapped = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                Text("Tap Correct Image")
                    .font(.headline)

                ForEach((0...2), id: \.self) { number in

                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(self.tapped && number == self.correctAnswer ? .green : .black) // you can do anything for animation
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.pictureTapped(number)
                    }

                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("answer the question"))
                .alert(isPresented: self.$showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Your score is \(score)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                        self.askQuestion()
                    })
                }

            }

        }
    }

    func pictureTapped(_ tag: Int) {

        tapped = true

        if tag == correctAnswer {
            score += 1
        } else {
            score -= 1
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.showAlert = true
        }
    }

    //Function to continue the game
    func askQuestion() {
        tapped = false
        showAlert = false
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)

    }

}

struct QuestionGame_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        QuestionGame()
    }
}
```

**P.S.** and no, I didn't find the way to show alert smoothly. For this case may be better to use `ZStack` and change the alert (or any other view) opacity from 0 to 1 (with animation), when you tap on image.

Comment: I am eager to test out. Thanks once again.

Comment: @ufookoro, glad that it helped you